# Mysql prepared statements - $mysqli->num_rows() returns 0

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Here is the code that I have problem with :

```
function getQuestions($mysqli, $subjectIdOrCode, $isStudent){                                                                                                     

    $idSubject = getSubjectId($mysqli, $subjectIdOrCode);                                                                                                         

    //writing the statement                                                                                                                                       
    $query = "select id,description from questions where id_subjects = ? and  
              is_for_student = ?";    

    //prepare statement                                                                                                                          
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    //binding the statement                                                                                                                                       
    $stmt->bind_param("si", $idSubject, $isStudent);                                                                                                              

    //execute the statement
    $stmt->execute();   

    //get the result  
    $result = $stmt->get_result();  

    //store the result                                                                                                                                            
    $stmt->store_result();     

    //get the number of rows                                                                                                                                      
    $noOfRows = $stmt->num_rows();  

    $questions = null;                                                                                                                                            
    for ($i = 0; $i < $noOfRows; $i++) {                                                                                                                          
        echo "test";
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $questions[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
        $questions[$i]['sno'] = $i+1;
        $questions[$i]['description'] = $row['description'];
    }

    return $questions;

}
```

When this function is called, nothing is printed (which implies that `$noOfRows` is 0). Now, when the line :

```
    //get the result
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
```

is removed, it prints `test` along with some error message that `$result` is undefined (which clearly shows that `$noOfRows` is > 0).

Where have I made a mistake in my code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

OK ... I have got your point. I have just put code to fetch num_rows

```
    //get the number of rows                                                                                                                                      
    $noOfRows = $stmt->num_rows;
```

Comment: I'm afraid you've misunderstood my question. I want to get the `number of rows` in object oriented format.

Comment: ok! Finally I've figured it out. Its `$result->num_rows` and not `$stmt->num_rows` when `$stmt->get_result()` is used.